# Jquery slideup/slidedown doesn't work second time

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to write a code that shows div boxes containing form elements based on a select box. I think the easiest way to explain this problem is to give an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/544rc/1/
If you look at this fiddle. Please try the following:

first select option 1, searchform 1 appears..which is right.
select option 3, search form 1 and 2 appear, which is also right
but now, when you select option 1 again. No form appears while it should show searchform 1.

I'm a rookie when it comes to jQuery so if my script isn't as pretty as it could be, you know the reason for that.

my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#select").change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "value1" || val == "value2") { //check if value 1 or 2 are selected

        $("#search2").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        $("#search1").slideUp("fast");

    } else {

        $("#search1").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        $("#search1").slideUp("fast");

    }

    $("#select").change(function() {

        var val = $(this).val();

        if (val == "value3" || val == "value4" || val == "value5") { // check if value 3, 4 or 5 are selected

            $("#search1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $("#search2").slideDown("fast");

        } else {

            $("#search1").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $("#search2").slideUp("fast");

        }
    });
});
```

});​

HTML:

```
<form id="indexsearch" method="post" action="#"> <!-- searchform -->
        <div class="soortselect">
            <label for="select">Ik zoek:</label>
            <select name="select" id="select" > <!-- select box -->
                <option value="">(choice)</option>
                <option value="value1">option 1</option>
                <option value="value2">option 2</option>
                <option value="value3">option 3</option>
                <option value="value4">option 4</option>
                <option value="value5">option 5</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="hide" id="search1"> <!--hidden search form 1 -->
            <div class="soortselect">
                <label for="edu">Opleiding</label>
                    <input name="edu" type="text" id="edu" ><br />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hide" id="search2"> <!-- hidden search form 2 -->
            <div class="soortselect">
                <label for="postal">Postcode</label>
                    <input name="postal" type="text" id="postal"><br />
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                     <input name="name" type="text" id="name"><br />
                    <input name="vind2" type="submit" id="vind" value="Vind!">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/544rc/4/

Based on what I see, you just needed to add another else if statement (checking for value 3,4,5).

I added another else if to slide up when `(choice)` is selected again.

Here's the updated Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //On Select Change...
    $("#select").change(function() {

        //Get Current Value
        var val = $(this).val();

        //If the value is the 1st or 2nd dropdown...
        if (val == "value1" || val == "value2") {
            //Slide down the second search form and slide up the first
            $("#search2").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $("#search1").slideUp("fast");
        } 
        //If the value is the 3rd, 4th, or 5th dropdown...
        else if(val == "value3" || val == "value4" || val == "value5") {
            //Slide down both the forms
            $("#search1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $("#search2").slideDown("fast");
        } 
        //If the value is nothing (choice is selected)...
        else{
            //Slide up both forms
            $("#search1").slideUp("fast");
            $("#search2").slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
});​
```

I deleted your original `else` statement because it wasn't needed.